# ¿Cómo contar los archivos que se envían por formulario y colocarles consecutivo?

Tags: html, python, flask

[Flask] Saludos. Espero me puedan ayudar con lo siguiente:
Cómo se podría crear un contador de todos los archivos que se envían por formulario, y luego asignarles un consecutivo a cada archivo, o sea que salgan LOT_imagen_001, LOT_imagen_002 etc ... Gracias de antemano.

Este es el código que tengo.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from werkzeug.datastructures import  FileStorage

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = './Archivos PDF'

@app.route("/")
def upload_file():
 return render_template('formulario.html')

@app.route("/upload", methods=['POST'])
def uploader():
 contador = 0
 ruta_raiz = './Archivos PDF'
 if request.method == 'POST':
  contador = contador + 1
  f = request.files['archivo']
  filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
  f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
  nombre_archivo = "LOT_{}".format(filename)
  os.rename(ruta_raiz + '\\' + filename, ruta_raiz + '\\' + nombre_archivo)
  return render_template('formulario.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run("0.0.0.0",8000,threaded=True,debug=True)
```

Este es mi formulario formulario.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Formulario</title>
</head>
<body>
    
  <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="archivo">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya que no manejas un registro de los archivos en BD, lo que puedes hacer en este caso son 2 cosas:

**1. Guardar el consecutivo en un archivo de texto, el cual vas a leer e incrementar cada ves que subas un archivo:**

consecutivo.txt

```
1
```

Funciones para gestionar el consecutivo

```
def get_counter():
    with open("consecutivo.txt", "r") as f:
        counter = f.readline()
        return counter.zfill(3)


def save_counter(counter):
    with open("consecutivo.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(str(int(counter.lstrip()) + 1))
```

---

O

2. Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Listar todos los archivos, ordenarlos por fecha de creación y luego obtener el primero de la lista.
- A este archivo le haces split para obtener el nombre del archivo y su extension.
- Como el patrón del consecutivo en una numeración de 3 dígitos `***_001`, debes de leer los 3 últimos caracteres del nombre del archivo y eliminar los zeros a la izquierda para luego incrementarlo en 1.

Funcion que obtiene el contador:

```
def get_counter():
    counter = str(1).zfill(3)
    os.chdir('./Archivos PDF')
    files = sorted(os.listdir('.'), key=os.path.getmtime)
    if len(files) > 0:
        file = files[0]
        filename, extension = os.path.splitext(file)
        counter = filename[-3:]
        counter = str(int(counter.lstrip())+1).zfill(3)
    return counter
```

Y aqui esta el endpoint donde guardas el archivo con el consecutivo:

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=['POST'])
def uploader():
    ruta_raiz = './Archivos PDF'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        contador = get_counter()
        f = request.files['archivo']
        s_filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(s_filename)
        nombre_archivo = "LOT_{}_{}{}".format(filename, contador, file_extension)
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], nombre_archivo))
        save_counter(contador)
    return redirect(request.url)
```

PD: Solo emplea una de las 2 opciones.